# Autoinstall from ISO File

Tags: 22.04, iso, autoinstall

Can someone suggest the steps to use the autoinstall function starting 22.04 Server ISO?

My goal is to use an ISO to install Ubuntu Server 22.04, and provide info for automating install (first user, package to install, partitioning...) without any human interaction at all.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately no guide about autoinstall and iso..

Comment: @user535733 thanks for your answer. I've edited the question.  I hope now is a bit clear my goal.

Comment: I've used this as a starting point. https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/ubuntu-22-04-server-autoinstall-iso Look through the comments as well. GL&HF

Comment: If cloud-init does NOT work with Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.
Do you have any solution to create ISO for autoinstall Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Look into [cloud-init](https://cloud-init.io/), which is intended for the described purpose on Ubuntu Server 22.04.

(cloud-init does NOT work with Ubuntu Desktop 22.04)